# WCHAN = 0 for a sleeping task?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, ps

I am a little confused about the status of a process I have.
It looks like this:

```
$ ps -eal | head -n 1 ; ps -eal | grep perf
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0  7843  7842  0  80   0 - 10838 -      pts/6    00:00:00 perf
```

-- so, the status is `S`, which the `man` page describes as *"S interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)"*, it is waiting for some event.
I assume it is listed in some waiting channel.
But the waiting channel is: `WCHAN -`.
Which `man` page describes with *"Running tasks will display a dash ('-') in this column."*

Plus, `/proc/7843/status` indeed contains `State:   S (sleeping)` and `/proc/7843/wchan` contains `0`. I guess `0` in `proc//wchan` tells the same thing -- that the task does not wait for anything.

Do I misunderstand something or do they contradict one another?

And the task indeed does not run -- I don't think `-` in `wchan` means it is waiting to be scheduled..

Could the `wchan` output be somehow misconfigured? I run Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-86-generic.

Checking other process shows:

```
$ ps -eal | head -n 1 ; ps -eal | grep fish
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  2407  2399  0  80   0 - 47675 wait   pts/0    00:00:07 fish
1 S  1000  2409     1  0  80   0 -  5500 poll_s ?        00:00:00 fishd
0 S  1000  2507  2399  0  80   0 - 45333 poll_s pts/3    00:00:00 fish
0 S  1000  2567     1  0  80   0 -  8366 wait   ?        00:00:00 fish
```

-- so here `WCHAN` is ok.

Comment: [Related answer on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/1041642/63769)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WCHAN value seems to be computed. From kernel sources `arch/x86/Kconfig`:

```
config SCHED_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER 
   Single-depth WCHAN output
   Calculate simpler /proc/<PID>/wchan values. If this option
   is disabled then wchan values will recurse back to the
   caller function. This provides more accurate wchan values,
   at the expense of slightly more scheduling overhead.
```

and from `Documentation/filesystem/proc.txt`:

```
wchan Present with CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y: it shows the kernel function
      symbol the task is blocked in - or "0" if not blocked.
```

so I guess sometimes there is a miscomputation of wchan.

Comment: However, OP demonstrated that in his case he get proper symbolic `wchan` information for some processes. With a  kernel mis-configuration it should never work, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the process state and wchan isn't returned atomically by the kernel.

That means between accessing the process' state and getting its wchan information its state may very well change from sleeping to running.

Thus, there is a race.

The [stack walking procedure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.9/source/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L916) inside the kernel for obtaining the wchan information is racy, as well and might not cover all cases.

You can cross-check with `cat /proc/$pid/stack` (root-only) or `cat /proc/$pid/syscall` to get some additional information on where the process is stuck in the kernel.

Comment: if I remember correctly, that `perf` command looked like stuck. But probably it did wake up very quickly to process some performance events and go back to sleep. Then indeed the state was changing too quickly and the kernel diagnostics did not keep up.